# How to move text below in every icon bottom nav

Tags: javascript, html, css, bottomnavigationview

I can move text to bottom of every icon. I am very besic programmer. just don't know that much. Please help me.  i have attached the whole css file formet

```
html {
             box-sizing: border-box;
             --bgColorMenu : #1d1d27;
           --duration: .7s;   
        }
    html *,
    html *::before,
    html *::after {
        box-sizing: inherit;
    }
    body{
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: hidden;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background-color: #d6cbd3;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
        transition: background-color var(--duration);
    }
    .menu{
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        /* Works well with 100% width  */
        width: 32.05em;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        padding: 0 0.85em;
        position: relative;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background-color: var(--bgColorMenu);   
    }
    .menu__item{
        
        all: unset;
        flex-grow: 1;
        z-index: 100;
        display: flex;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 50%;
        align-items: center;
        will-change: transform;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 0.55em 0 0.85em;
        transition: transform var(--timeOut , var(--duration));   
    }
    .menu__item::before{
        
        content: "";
        z-index: -1;
        width: 4.2em;
        height: 4.2em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        transform: scale(0);
        transition: background-color var(--fduration), transform var(--duration);
    }
    .menu__item.active {
        transform: translate3d(0, -.8em , 0);
    }
    .menu__item.active::before{   
        transform: scale(1);
        background-color: var(--bgColorItem);
    }
    .icon{   
        width: 2.6em;
        height: 2.6em;
        stroke: white;
        fill: transparent;
        stroke-width: 1pt;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-linejoin: round;
        stroke-dasharray: 400;
    }
    .menu__item.active .icon {
        animation: strok 1.5s reverse;
    }
    
    @keyframes strok {
        100% {
            stroke-dashoffset: 400;
        }
    }
    .menu__border{
        left: 0;
        bottom: 99%;
        width: 10.9em;
        height: 2.4em;
        position: absolute;
        clip-path: url(#menu);
        will-change: transform;
        background-color: var(--bgColorMenu);
        transition: transform var(--timeOut , var(--duration));
    }
    .svg-container {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
    
    
      @media screen and (max-width: 50em) {
           .menu{
                font-size: .8em;
          }
    }
    
    .text{
        
        
    }

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cfFy.png
```

I can move text to bottom of every icon. I am very besic programmer. just don't know that much. Please help me.  i have attached the whole css file formet
I can move text to bottom of every icon. I am very besic programmer. just don't know that much. Please help me.  i have attached the whole css file formet
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O07Mq.png)

Comment: change the below text <span > to <div> . using span means inline will be take place so new line would not be set . using div , the text will be chnaged its position to the below image

Answer (score 0):

You already have `display: flex;` on the parent button element (`.menu__item`),  which means all child elements are now flex items.

Without being able to test your code, I would assume all you need is to add `flex-direction: column;` which changes the flow direction for flex items (from horizontal to vertical):

```css
.menu__item {
    ...
    flex-direction: column;
    ...
}
```